# Other words to describe the relationships between pieces of data with a common parent/child

Tags: word-choice

I'm writing a program that makes/utilizes arbitrary relationships between pieces of data, and I can't think of more generic terms for the user interface than:
[image: Node relationships]
Co-parent: The relationship between A and B
Sibling: The relationship between D and E
Should I stick with these? Or are there better names? The relationships defined by the arrows in the diagram aren't necessarily hierarchical, they're more along the lines of 'A is like C except for X'

Comment: Of course the individual boxes are commonly called "nodes", and the boxes with no children are "leaf" nodes.  Relationships, in a tree structure, are generally called parent/child (with grandparent/grandchild, etc, occasionally used).  Children with the same parent are generally "siblings", but I don't ever recall a relationship being described as "cousin" or "uncle" or "niece" (though probably in part because there's rarely a need to describe such relationships).  I can't recall any other term used for siblings other than "adjacent".  Never heard "co-parent" used, or any equivalent term, but-

Comment: "inverted tree" and "mesh" structures are much rarer than tree structures.

Comment: If A and B are connected somehow, I suppose you can call them _spouses_. If they're not, perhaps _divorcees_?

Comment: From a computer science standpoint, I think "co-parent" doesn't get used because normally nodes in a tree like structure do not have multiple parents -- multiple parents implies there's something weird about the tree/graph, like there's a cycle somewhere, or that there isn't a single root (you cannot reach B if you start travelling from A).  I think normally "C" would be thought of as the root/parent, and "A" and "B" as children, regardless of the "direction" of the relationship, and thus "A" and "B" would still be siblings.

Comment: I can't reconcile your use of arrows with your statement that the relationships aren't hierarchical. I get that you're probably being deliberately vague about the precise nature of the data, but without further contextual details, I'm afraid we're all taking stabs in the dark.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't think *divorcees* would be a useful term unless A and B had previously been connected and had become disconnected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term "sibling" is common usage in this context, yes.

I haven't heard "co-parent", but "parent" is the usual term in a tree structure, so "co-parent" sounds about right.

Answer (score 3):

It’s hard to tell how to answer this well without a better understanding of the relationship you’re talking about.

1. If “A → C” means “A is like C except for *(some factor)*”,
   it seems as though the relationship is not just not hierarchical;
   it is anti-hierarchical, and symmetric,
   so it should be written “A ↔ C” and “B ↔ C”.
2. If the relationship between A and C is “A is like C except for *(some factor)*”, does that mean that A is like ***B*** except for that factor?
   If so, the relationship seems to be transitive,
   so “A ↔ C” and “B ↔ C” implies “A ↔ B”, i.e., the relationship between A and B is *the same* as that between A and C, and between B and C.
3. Or does it mean that A is like B, *even considering* the factor (e.g., a lion is like a cat except for size; a tiger is like a cat except for size; a lion is like a tiger.)?
4. Or does it mean that A is like B, except for two factors (e.g., a lion is like a cat except for size; a lion is like a bear except for genus)?

Based on what you’ve given us, if case #3 applies, these might be what you want:

- A and B are *comparable*
- A and B are *in the same cohort*
- A and B are *cohorts*         (although some might say that this is an incorrect usage of that word)

And if case #4 applies, consider

- A and B are *cousins* (or *distant cousins*)

In any case, when talking or writing about this,
you would need to define the term you are using.